# catching error breaks for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
    for (var i = 0, len = IDs.length; i < len; i++) {

    entry = IDs[i];
    isAnyFailure = false;

    try{
    var id = db.getSiblingDB("door").jhi_user.findOne({"_id" : entry});
    } catch (err){

     failedIDs.push(entry);
     failedCount++;
     isAnyFailure = true;
    }

...
}
```

if it catches any error, it will continue to code or it will go to next iteration?

Comment: why don't you log your code, or step through in a debugger and see?

Comment: It should continue with the next iteration..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop continues in try and catch:

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      try
      {
        if(i == 6)
        {
          document.getElementById('noid').html("x"); //this will cause an exception as no such ID exists
        }
        console.log("In try Iteration :: "+i);
      }
      catch (err)
      {
        console.log("In catch Iteration :: "+i);
      }
    }
```

The whole concept of try and catch is to continue the execution if an exception occurs rather than abruptly stopping the program / script.